# Using react with a current project

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I want to use react with a current jquery project which uses underscore templates to render UI.What are the pros/cons of the approach and how can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

A major con would be that jQuery and React aren't primarily used in unison. You can often accomplish everything you need in React, without jQuery.

However, React is flexible enough to throw in almost any project. You will be able to use it in your project if you need. Just know, there is a better way.